# Does std::allocator handle over-aligned types in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment, allocator

C++17 introduces `std::aligned_alloc` and alignment-aware `new` that can do over-aligned allocations, but what about `std::allocator`? Does it handle over-aligned types?

Comment: oops, I deleted my wrong answer , a copy-paste horror story ... ( feel free to down vote me ... :) )

Comment: Yes, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html removed the text making it implementation defined.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Never mind, I've found the section in N4659(C++17 DIS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In N4659(C++17 DIS), [23.10.9.1 [allocator.members], bullet 2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/default.allocator)

> T* allocate(size_t n);
>
> Returns: A pointer to the initial element of an array of storage of size n * sizeof(T), **aligned appropriately for objects of type T**.

Compared to C++14, the sentence

> It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported

has been removed. So `std::allocator` should support over-aligned types in C++17.

Comment: uhm, N4659 ( the pdf version I found at www.open-std.org  ) still reads verbatim as per my original answer, that is that overaligned types support  is implementation defined ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I found it at https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp, not sure the one at www.open-std.org.

Comment: ok reading Marc Glisse's comment is clear you're right ( good to know that the allocation functions takes also an alignment parameter now  ).

Comment: Could you click accept this answer? This is very why aligned_allocator is not longer neccessary.

Comment: @Jamboree This is great. Thanks for digging this up.