# clang c++17 std::vector over aligned types copy of elements SIGSEGV when compiled with -mavx

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399544/does-stdallocator-handle-over-aligned-types-in-c17) I thought that in C++17 a std::vector with default allocator should handle over aligned types. However, the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t Alignment>
struct alignas(Alignment) AlignedArray : public std::array<T, N>
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const AlignedArray& a)
    {
        std::copy(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(o, " "));
        return o;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Array = AlignedArray<double, 24, 64>;
    std::vector<Array> v(10);
    for(const auto& e : v)
    {
        auto arr(e);
        std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

segfaults on the creation of `arr` when I compile it with clang 6.0.1 and `-mavx`. Without the `-mavx` switch it runs fine (CPU is a E5-2697 v2). I compiled it with
`clang++ -I<path_to_libcxx>/include/c++/v1 -g -mavx -std=c++17 main.cpp -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -o alignastest  -L<path_to_libcxx>/lib -L<path_to_libcxxabi>/lib`.
I am running this on an old RHEL 6.9 where I compiled clang 6.0.1 and libcxx, libcxxabi.
I tested it on another system (Ubuntu 18.10, gcc 8) and it works without any problems.

## Sub Question

Regarding the alignment, I found out that the implementation of `std::aligned_alloc` in libc++ relies on a C11 feature which is only enabled with a recent glibc version (`__config.h`):

```
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2, 17)
#define _LIBCPP_HAS_C11_FEATURES
#endif
```

Unfortunately RHEL 6.9 has only `ldd (GNU libc) 2.12` installed. Is `alignas` also depending on the glibc version?

Comment: I tested this on my system, works with g++ 8, does not work with clang++ 6. I looked at the compiled program, and g++ does not use avx instructions even with -mavx for the std::copy while clang does. Also the instruction faulting is vmovaps (aligned 256bit move) from the address of the first array to ymm0, hope this helps someone to debug this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I use `-std=c++17`, I get a correctly aligned memory block.

Comment: It seems that libc++ did not yet have support for over-aligned types in version 6.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Look at the header <memory> and search for anything about alignment. There is a lot in the current version, but almost nothing in version 6.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem with the compiled code, however, I have not found a solution yet. But it seams, that this is only a clang issue and using g++ fixes it.

The problem is best illustrated by showing some of the resulting assembly code. The `auto arr(e);` code line gets compiled to some move instructions to copy the data from the vector to the stack, clang uses (when compiling with -mavx) avx2 instructions like the following (AT&T syntax):

```
vmovaps 0xa0(%rax),%ymm0
vmovaps %ymm0,0x120(%rsp)
...
```

Where %rax is the address of the current array in the vector. The target arr is located at 0x80(%rsp). The program would copy over in 32byte chunks (256 bit avx2 instructions).

However the problem becomes clear, when looking at the values: `%rax = 0x55555556be70` in my debugging test. the problem is, that vmovaps (move aligned packed single precision) to a 256bit avx2 register expects, that the target and source are aligned at 256bit or 32byte (0x20) boundaries, however %rax is only 16byte aligned. When compiling without the alignas, clang uses vmovups (the same instruction, but does not require the data to be aligned).

So the issue is, that the allocator of std::vector does not respect the alignas and does not align the array at 64byte boundaries. g++ does also not align the array inside the vector to 32byte boundaries and does not use avx instructions when not also using -O[not 0]. However g++ always uses the 128bit xmm registers, which only need alignment to 16bytes, to which the allocator alignes the data with both compilers.

EDIT:

I just realized, that I forgot to compile with -std=c++17. with that flag it works for me with clang++. The code looks the same, but the allocator correctly aligns the code at a 64byte boundary. So I guess it has to do with an old library. Maybe you can send me your binary, then I could take a more detailed look at it.

Comment: Strange that avx2 instructions are used when compiled with -mavx. Does this still happen if you compile with -std=c++17? Thank you for your help, here is a link two the binaries, once with avx and once without avx: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8xjzqfmvjisb6k7/AAC1NvA7AR16DyuvH4RYODtJa?dl=0"

Comment: Are you using clang with libc++ or libstdc++?

Comment: I tried both, compiling with libc++ and libstdc++. Both work when using c++17 for me, but only the libstdc++ fails without c++17. But libc++ with std < c++17 does not respect alignas correctly, but aligns at 32byte, which is enough for avx2 instructions

Comment: @AlexanderDaum Before C++17, `::operator new` used by `std::allocator::allocate` (used by `std::vector` by default) was not able to allocate memory for over-aligned types.

Comment: I still get same error when I use it with 32byte alignment :( I guess it has something todo with some other old library (maybe glibc) on this RHEL 6.9 system.

Comment: I tested your program and have the same effect as I do, when using libc++ but std < c++17. The array is aligned at 32bytes. It probably fails on your machine, because I have a newer version of libc++, or some other library. I guess the only way that it works on your machine is to not use an aligned array and have the compiler generate unaligned access.