# Datatype works with MPI_Scatter but not MPI_Gather

Tags: c++, mpi

I am having some trouble with the MPI_Gather function. I made a simple program to practice MPI. I have debugged the program and it functions correctly on the scatter however the gather function gives an invalid datatype error. I am unsure about what is wrong as the datatype is sent correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The program is currently only using one process for easier debugging and as such the size of `smallSet` is equal to that of `largeSet`. The size of `largeSet` will scale with the number of processes used.

```
using position = __m128d;

int main()
{

    //make values for sizes
    int rank, size;
    const int smallSetSize = 4;
    const int totalSize = 4; 


    //start MPI, get rank and size
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    //make data types
    std::array<position, smallSetSize> *smallSet = new std::array<position, smallSetSize>;
    std::array<position, totalSize> *largeSet = new std::array<position, totalSize>;
    position step = _mm_set1_pd(1.0);


    //initial data
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++)
        {
            (*largeSet)[i][0] = 1.0 * i;
            (*largeSet)[i][1] = 1.0 * i;
        }
    }

    //make MPI datatype for __m128d
    MPI_Datatype AVXDouble2Vector;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(position), MPI_BYTE, &AVXDouble2Vector);

    //send data to relevant nodes
    MPI_Scatter(largeSet, smallSetSize, AVXDouble2Vector, smallSet, smallSetSize, AVXDouble2Vector, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // add 1 to each value
    for (int i = 0; i < smallSetSize; i++)
    {
        (*smallSet)[i] = _mm_add_pd((*smallSet)[i],step);
    }

    //recieve data on root node
    MPI_Gather(smallSet, smallSetSize, AVXDouble2Vector, largeSet, smallSetSize, AVXDouble2Vector, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: I think you use `MPI_Scatter` incorrectly. Its second argument is a _number of elements sent to each process_. How can you send to each process 4 different elements, if the source array `largeSet` on the root only contains 4 elements? Don't you actually want to _broadcast_ `largeSet` from the root? By `MPI_Bcast`? Also, it seems that `MPI_Gather` is inappropriate for the similar reason. Don't you actually want to _reduce_ the results? By `MPI_Reduce`? See the pictures here: https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/.

Comment: This is only using one node at the moment to make the debugging easier so node 0 will receive and send all the data. If I expanded to 2 nodes I would give `largeSet` 8 elements instead and each node would still receive 4 elements.

Comment: You should specify this in the question itself. Note that one node doesn't imply a single MPI process. In HPC world, "node" usually means a node of a supercomputer / HPC cluster, where multiple MPI processes may run at once.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that you forgot to call `MPI_Type_commit` after `MPI_Type_contiguous`. See: [a datatype object has to be committed before it can be used in communication](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node86.htm#Node86). Note that you should _free_ the committed data type before your program terminates.

Comment: As a point of style, the use of `new` is considered bad practice these days. Use `std::vector`. As another point of style, I don't like the way you're passing buffers. You're using the fact that `std::array` allocates precisely the elements, but your code takes too much thinking to convince myself that it's correct. Also, your code may suffer from alignment issues. Or it may not. It's just not obvious to me.

Comment: It's true that to dynamically allocate an object of type `std::array` seems at least weird. Either use `std::array` without dynamic allocation, or `std::vector` if you don't know the number of elements at compile time. Combining `std::array` with `new` does not make much sense. Also be careful about the mentioned alignment. In case of dynamic allocations, some check for `alignof(__m128d)` against `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` may be useful. AFAIK, since C++17, `operator new` should support overaligned types, but not before. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400243/580083.

Comment: Ahh that works. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.